# Copy Range from sheet to another with destination formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, range

I was attempting to copy a range from one excel sheet to another :

```
wfrom.Worksheets(fromSheet).Range(fromRange).Copy
wTo.Worksheets(toSheet).Range(toRange).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

But this clears the destination formating(Destinatin range has backgound colour which I need to keep)

How can I modify the code to keep destination formating?

Comment: `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` will not overwrite desitnation formatting. Are you sure those colors are not from conditional formatting?

Comment: Thank you. I got what the issue was!  used the clear function to clear the destination range before above code which cleared the formatting aswell. Changed it to clearcontents and solved the issue!